# NSTextView round corners and draw background

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nstextview

For two I've been working on following problem:

I'm supposed to create message chat view which is going to be placed in `NSTableView`. It has to have color background, rounded corners, custom margins. I tried with `NSTextField` but with no success. I have desired background and rounded corners but text is not displayed correctly because it starts in the center of the field in case of multiline. Also I tried with `NSTextView`, which seems to be better solution in this situation, but I couldn't set rounded corners. I tried using `[textView.layer setCornerRadius:7.0];` but it gives no effect.

Thanks for any reply!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add it to Text View property

[image]

```
[self.textView setWantsLayer:YES];
[self.textView.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
```

And you can see>

[image]

But you Scroll View backgroundColor should be WindowBackgroundcolor

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yup, it's working, thanks a lot : ) Actually I did it in other way because since I want it to put to the `NSTableView` and I don't want it to scroll I created custom `NSView` and made it rounded and with background, then I place Label (which is `NSTextField`) in it and made it transparent. So it's another solution but thanks a lot anyway : )